# BLOCKING read repair blocks writes on other replicas?

Tags: cassandra

Learning Cassandra. There are a couple of things about read repair that I don't understand.

The docs say this about BLOCKING read repair:

> If a read repair is triggered, the read blocks writes sent to other replicas until the consistency level is reached by the writes.

To be honest, this entire sentence just doesn't make sense to me. First, *why* would read repair need to block writes? Isn't read repair in essence just a simple write of reconciled data? Second, *how* can read repair block writes on *another replicas*?

The docs also say that BLOCKING read repair breaks partition level write atomicity.

> Cassandra attempts to provide partition level write atomicity, but since only the data covered by a SELECT statement is repaired by a read repair, read repair can break write atomicity when data is read at a more granular level than it is written. For example, read repair can break write atomicity if you write multiple rows to a clustered partition in a batch, but then select a single row by specifying the clustering column in a SELECT statement.

Again, I don't understand how write atomicity gets broken. Single-partition batch is atomic and isolated, right? Can someone explain it more?

What implications this breaking of atomicity has for developers? I mean, it sure doesn't sound good.

**EDIT:**
For the first question see the accepted answer. For the second question [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14593) explains how atomicity gets broken.

Comment: Can you provide link from where you are reading or where it is mentioned?

Comment: @Manish Khandelwal https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/read_repair.html

Comment: I have copied info into my summary from a bunch of places, and now can't find it. Some of it is from the link provided. I'll get back to you when I find it.

Comment: @Manish Khandelwal here https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/ddl.html#read-repair-options

Comment: huh, I've only just noticed that the docs say two different things in two places: first link says that "read blocks ON writes", second link – that "read blocks writes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see where the docs are a bit confusing. Allow me to expand on the subject and hopefully clarify it for you.

The wording in this paragraph could probably use a rewrite:

> If a read repair is triggered, the read blocks writes sent to other replicas until the consistency level is reached by the writes.

It's referred to as a *blocking read-repair* because the reads are blocked (result is not returned to the client/driver by the coordinator) until the problematic replicas are repaired. The mutation/write is sent to the offending replica and the replica must acknowledge that the write is successful (i.e. persisted to commitlog).

The read-repair does not block ordinary writes -- it's just that the read request by the coordinator is blocked until the offending replica(s) involved in the request is repaired.

For the second part of your question, it's an extreme case where that scenario would take place because it's really a race condition between the batch and the read-repair. I've worked on a lot of clusters and I've never ran into that situation (maybe I'm just extremely lucky ). I've certainly never had to worry about it before.

It has to be said that read-repairs are a problem because replicas miss mutations. In a distributed environment, you would expect the odd dropped mutation. But if it's a regular occurrence in the cluster, read-repair is the least of your worries since you probably have a bigger underlying issue -- unresponsive nodes from long GC pauses, commitlog disks not able to keep up with writes. Cheers!

Comment: Beat me to it!  Nicely put.  And I'll second your extreme case, where I've built a couple hundred clusters in my time, and also _never_ ran into that situation.  So while probable, I agree that it's highly unlikely.

Comment: Cheers, @Aaron! 